# How to convert word document to PDF without formating the table of content

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word

When converting word document to PDF, the computer produces a document with formatted table of content page numbers. How can this be stopped?

Answer (score 0):

In case your problem is that bookmarks are added to the PDF document, automatically generated from the headings in the Word document, you can disable this using File -> Save As -> .pdf -> More options... -> Options... -> Uncheck Create bookmarks using:. [image]

Answer (score -1):

### Steps to Convert MS Word Document to PDF Format (Windows & Mac)

Many a time we need to submit documents in the PDF format. So, knowing the steps to perform the task is very important for all. Here, we have explained the steps in details for both the Windows and the Mac users. Read the further lines to learn how to convert word document to PDF.

**Windows:**

At first, open the MS Word file that you want to convert to PDF. After that, click on the File tab, that is at the upper section of the window. Next, select Export. Further, click on "Create PDF/XPS Document", that is at the upper left-hand side of the window. After that, click on Create PDF/XPS. Now, a window will pop-up, it enables you to select a location where you want to save the file is in the form of PDF. Lastly, name the file and tap on the Enter key.

**Mac:**

Launch the MS Word file at first. Next, click on the File tab that is at the top section of the window. After that, click on the "Save As" option under the menu. Now, edit the file name and then select a location where you want to Save. Also, drop-down the menu for File Format, and under the available options select PDF. Lastly, click on the Export button.

## **Change Word Document to PDF via Google Drive**

Open Google Drive. If you are not signed in to your Google Account then enter the details for that to continue the process. Now, at the left-hand side of the Google Drive window you will see New with an additional symbol, click on it. After that, select the "File upload" option from the menu, and then select the Word document by navigating to its location. Further, click on the Open button. When the file gets uploaded, open the Word document. Next, click on File, and then hit on the "Download as" option. Lastly, select PDF Document (.pdf) to complete the task.